# More than basis vectors in a space are dependent, less can't span the space proof

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space, $ B = \{ \mathbf{b}_{1}, \ldots, \mathbf{b}_{n} \}$ a basis for $V$ (independent and spans $V$).
Prove that fewer vectors than $n$ can't span $V$, while more vectors are necessarily dependent.

I am looking for a clearer proof than the one on this page: https://math.kennesaw.edu/~plaval/math3260/basis.pdf (middle of third page, Theorem 306), and/or an explanation as to why that system of equations helps prove linear dependence (says to consider said linear combination, but doesn't really explain anything).

Thanks!

Comment: What is your definition of a basis?

Comment: A set in V that's linearly independent and spans V

Comment: Assume $C=(b_2,\dotsc,b_n)$ spans the space. What is $b_1$ in terms of $C$? Could $(b_1,\dotsc,b_n)$ still be linearly independent?

Comment: Since ***B*** is an independent set ***b1*** can't be expressed in terms of ***C***, so I guess this applies to this set, but what of a different (random) one?

Comment: see theorem 1 and its proof at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theorem_for_vector_spaces

Comment: Thanks, I am familiar with this proof; was just wondering whether there was a non iterative/computer-program-like one

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, assume for contradiction that $B \setminus \{ \mathbf{b}_{n} \} = \{ \mathbf{b}_{1}, \ldots, \mathbf{b}_{n - 1} \}$ spans $V$. Then there exists $c_{1}, \ldots, c_{n - 1} \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbf{b}_{n} = c_{1} \mathbf{b}_{1} + \cdots + c_{n - 1} \mathbf{b}_{n - 1}$. But this would mean that $c_{1} \mathbf{b}_{1} + \cdots + c_{n - 1} \mathbf{b}_{n - 1} + (-1) \mathbf{b}_{n} = \mathbf{0}$, so $B$ is linearly dependent, a contradiction.

Similarly, let $B' = B \cup \{ \mathbf{b}_{n + 1} \} = \{ \mathbf{b}_{1}, \ldots, \mathbf{b}_{n + 1} \}$, where $\mathbf{b}_{n + 1} \in V$. Then since $V = \operatorname{span} (B)$, there exist constants $c_{1}, \ldots, c_{n} \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $c_{1} \mathbf{b}_{1} + \cdots + c_{n} \mathbf{b}_{n} = \mathbf{b}_{n + 1}$. But this would mean that $c_{1} \mathbf{b}_{1} + \cdots + c_{n} \mathbf{b}_{n} + (- 1) \mathbf{b}_{n + 1} = \mathbf{0}$, so $B'$ is dependent.

Comment: What about other random sets in ***V*** with more or fewer elements than in ***B***? Sorry I wasn't clear enough

Comment: My apologies. They're constructing certain "change of basis" matrices, and then using facts about matrices (namely, relations between the number of rows and number of columns) to pull out some quick and dirty results.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to look it over again with that in mind .

Comment: Just keep in mind that a system of equations is represented by a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give a (slightly) different answer.

> Let $V$ be a vector space, $ B = \{ b_1, \ldots, b_n \}$ a basis for $V$ (independent and spans $V$).
>   Prove that (1) fewer vectors than $n$ can't span $V$, while (2) more vectors are necessarily dependent.

Proof: (1) $B$ is a linearly independent set, so if we take one element out, say $b_i \in B \subset V$,

$$b_i = \sum_{j = 1\\ j \neq i}^n c_j b_j$$
would imply a contradiction.
So $b_i \in V$ is surely *not* in $\text{Span}(\{ b_1, \ldots, b_{i-1}, b_{i+1}, \ldots, b_n \})$.

(2) Choose a non zero $w \in V$, $w \neq b_i$ for all $i$.
Since $w \in \text{Span}(B) = V$,

$$w = \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i b_i $$

implies that $C = B \cup \{w\}$ is a linearly dependent set. $\square$